# Recovery of unsaved 40 minute long video on Samsung A32

Tags: samsung, data-recovery, storage, video, video-recording

I took a video of approximately 40 minutes long this morning at a funeral. I stopped taking the video and waited for it to "process". It took very long, so I switched my phone off. But now I can't find it anywhere on my A32 Samsung. It is not in the recycling or trash bins. I also can't find it on Google photo's. Is there any way that I might be able to retrieve it? I was the only one that took a video, so it is very important to the family.

Comment: I'm sorry for your loss.  I truly hope someone is able to help you with this issue.  I had a similar experience with an important video that was not saved (on an LG Android device), and unfortunately I was not able to recover it.  Hopefully someone will find a solution for you.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate your response!

Comment: You're welcome.  I feel for you.  One thing I can recommend - *and I know it's not ideal* - is for now, to not use the device at all, if possible.  Don't turn it off, but just plug it in and let it sleep.  That way, as little will get written to storage on the device as possible.  That will possibly buy you a little time to see if anyone has any good ideas.  (BTW, if you find good ideas elsewhere, please do post them as answers here... good quality self-answers are always welcome!)

Comment: I've added a few more tags to your question in hope that others may find it and provide helpful answers.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket, I am new on this platform. I wrote an answer below. Then, the community bot said that my answer is unclear. Can you please help me to understand if my answer is unclear and how to improve it ? Thanks. :-)

Comment: @Job_September_2020 Welcome!  Likely, a human reviewer found the answer you provided lacking in some regard (even though it says "Community Bot", I think that's a problem with StackExchange).  The "lacking" is probably that the answer partially says "to Google it".  Now, personally, I think your answer adds sufficient additional information to be valuable (as the OP confirmed), but human reviews are subject to human opinions (and error).  Overall, I think your answer is useful, but relies too much on "Google it".  Self-contained answers are best and are often upvoted.  I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Job_September_2020 BTW, technically, the "correct" place to ask your question would be in this SE's Meta (https://android.meta.stackexchange.com), but I'm a flexible person! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. One option is to take your phone to a professional data recovery
   center, and they will try to recover the video for you.

   For example, if you google "**Phone Data Recovery**", you can see
   lots of services available. You can add your local city to google
   search "**Phone Data Recovery in My City (such as Seattle, Miami, Toronto,...)**" and it may recommend some
   local services in your city if there is any available.
2. Another option is to google "**Android Phone Data Recovery Software**" to  see if there is any **recovery
   software** either free or paid, which could be used to recover the
   video. However, since you have not installed the software before
   your record the video, the potentially **BIG** issue is that if you install a
   **recovery software** now after you already lose the video, the new software may be installed over your lost video and you will lose that video. **So, I will not recommend this option for your current situation.**

---

Since you switched off the phone while the video was being saved, the video may not be properly created on your phone yet, and that makes it even more difficult to recover than the case where you accidentally delete a good and working video.  However, I still hope that the professional service centers can help. Good luck.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you, I understood your answer very well and I appreciate your advice!

Comment: @Marieta, I appreciate your reply. Best wishes. :-)